# Why isn't image placed in the most upper left corner of html page?

Tags: html, css, image

I got a extra-super-simple html page with one image as the only content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Anzeige</title>
</head>
<body>
       <img alt="Anzeige" src="images/image.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

In Safari and Firefox (and also in UIWebView, which is my original problem) the image is not shown in the upper left corner, but with a small white edge of about 5 pixels. When I load the image alone into Firefox it's the same, but with Safari and UIWebView it's shown without the border in the most upper left corner.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about the default page margins. Add this CSS:

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to reset the browser default padding and margins to 0 using:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

How it works is all browsers have default padding and margins implemented, adding that to your CSS file it will reset all browsers margins and padding to 0px.

This code will cover ALL browser default programs you will ever have:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
License: none (public domain)

*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: exactly! set body and * margins/paddings to zero (0)

Comment: @Tobiask using `*` is discouraged as it is browser intensive, thus Eric Mayers is a much more efficient way of doing things.